# How can I add an email to an automation I started in sendgrid?

Tags: automation, sendgrid

I have an email automation I started in send grid. After a few days I decided that I wanted to send a follow up email to that same list.

If I pause the automation and add the email and set the automation live again will it send the people on my list the new email?

I've seen another poster recommend duplicating the automation but I don't understand what the expected behavior of that would be.

I've tried pausing the automation adding the email and setting it to live again, but the email hasn't been triggered yet. The email is supposed to start after three days and I'm very close to that but not sure if it has been exactly 72 hours yet. I'm trying to understand the expected behavior to know if I'm all set and should just wait for the email to trigger.